# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hotshot'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to port python 2.7 code to python 3.7 code

I am seeing an "import hotshots" in a file but getting a

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hotshot'

I can't seem to find that module anywhere online. Is this a python 2.7 specific package replaced with something else ? I had that case with cStringIO

Additional info : this is implemented in a Django project. Maybe an older Django lib ? I am trying to port this code from Django 1.8 to 2.2

What I tried to do :
- pip install --upgrade hotshot

> No matching distribution found for hotshot

Looking for hotshot on The Python Package Index

> No library with that name

What it is used for ? The only line where it is used is

> `prof = hotshot.Profile(final_log_file)`

The whole project code is available here :
https://github.com/EbookFoundation/fef-questionnaire, 
the file using "hotshot" is "profiler.py". Additionnally, there are no "hotshot.py" file in the whole project.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found something. `hotshot` was a Python profiler (https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/hotshot.html :

> hotshot was an experimental C module that focused on minimizing the
>   overhead of profiling, at the expense of longer data post-processing
>   times. It is no longer maintained and may be dropped in a future
>   version of Python.

I simply have to replace hotshot by a newer Python profiler, compatible with Python 3 :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

So either `profile` or `cProfile`.